# Showing a cross-fade (or other) transition when changing a control's content

Tags: c#, silverlight, animation, silverlight-4.0

I have a Silverlight control with a Content field. I'd like to be able to programmatically switch the child control that appears in that field, and to show an animated transition between the old content and the new. What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a TransitioningContentContol instead of a ContentControl. [How-to Video here](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/all/silverlight-toolkit-animatedtransition-control/) (the control is in system.Windows.Controls.Layout.Toolkit)

It is now part of the released toolkit (the video is old).

Hope this helps.